Android Studio. Gradle Sync error: Could not move temporary workspace
I am making a new project in Android Studio, but I have a problem when it is syncing gradle for the first time and I can't do anymore.
I get these error messages:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\ACER\AndroidStudioProjects\CamaraX\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af-0241f059-0743-498d-b994-7c82e3b551d2) to immutable location (C:\Users\ACER\AndroidStudioProjects\CamaraX\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af)
> Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\ACER\AndroidStudioProjects\CamaraX\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af-0241f059-0743-498d-b994-7c82e3b551d2) to immutable location (C:\Users\ACER\AndroidStudioProjects\CamaraX\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af)
...
* Exception is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\ACER\AndroidStudioProjects\CamaraX\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af-0241f059-0743-498d-b994-7c82e3b551d2) to immutable location (C:\Users\ACER\AndroidStudioProjects\CamaraX\.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af)
...
Caused by: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace
...
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

I tried switching to a newer version, but the same thing happens and with older versions I get this:
Minimum supported Gradle version is 8.6. Current version is 8.5.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings.
Change Gradle version in Gradle wrapper to 8.6 and re-import project
Open Gradle wrapper properties
Gradle Settings.


I found a solution by modifying two files in an answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/78478363/18302773
In libs.versions.toml “agp = ‘8.4.0’” changes to “agp = ‘8.3.0’" and in gradle-wrapper.properties "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-bin.zip" changes to "distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.5-bin.zip".
After making those changes, it worked.
I was even able to later upgrade to the latest versions by changing the lines in the files manually (not using the Upgrade Assistant).

Have you installed any AI assistant plugins?
I installed Codeium and found that this directory is occupied by Codeium's Language Server.
When I disabled it, there were no more errors.

I stopped it from task manager and it worked :)

To resolve the issue, change the folder name from:
dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af-0241f059-0743-498d-b994-7c82e3b551d2 
to:
dcbcd87108cec70bb467e05d5172bee8efb944af
Repeat this process as needed, and it will work!

I was running into this same issue, such a nightmare. I went into
/app/gradle/libs.versions.toml and changed the agp version to 8.3.0
and
/app/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and changed it to 8.5
and this fixed all issues
I also followed what @user25096281 mentioned. I uninstalled Codeium and made a new project. It worked without issue. I then reinstalled and it was all good, for now

Gradle was unable to move some files, but you can try moving them manually.
1: Go to the specified location and rename the file (the file Gradle is trying to move) to the name of the folder (where Gradle is trying to move the file).
2: Close the project in Android Studio, and then reopen it.
If you encounter a similar error again, repeat the above steps.


uninstall any ai plugins and restart the IDE to solve it permanently.
OR

rename those specific files which it says could not move to where it was supposed to be. for example if the error looks like: could not move temporary workspace 123 to to immutable location 12234. just go to the location and change 123 to 12234. this will solve it for that project but the issue ma arise later in other projects.



Thank you, I hate that the solution was so annoyingly simple. Copying the folder manually helped me solve this issue and finally upgrade React Native above 0.74.x

I've also encountered the problem.
As I've found out so far, this problem might be caused by the antivirus software installed on our devices. It monitors the whole filesystem and would potentially mess the build process up. Other programs with similar behaviour will cause this error as well, I think.
You can go to this issue on Gradle GitHub repository, where developers are trying to settle the issue and have come up with some theories. There is a post on Gradle Forums, and you can keep an eye on it for other ways to settle this.
For now, a possible solution is to temporarily turn off the antivirus software while building, which works for me.

could not move temporary workspace android studio how to fix it
just put off the all antivirus software that you have install in window 10 or 11 and also put off the windwo firewall after that run it again the bug will be automatically fixed.

Inside your project directory run this command:
npx react-native run-android

then:
npm start --reset-cache
again run this command:
npx react-native run-android
If the same error still occurs, go to the root directory of your project, navigate to the android folder, open the gradle.properties file, and change newArchEnabled=true to newArchEnabled=false:
newArchEnabled=false
This solution worked in my case; I hope it works well for you too.

Just make sure to exclude your gradle & project folder at your antivirus if you still need the antivirus on
