Problems with android studio - “Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync"
I have a problem with the application because when I start it and try to open the layout it does not work and the screen displays a message saying “Design editor is unavailable until after a successful project sync”, if anyone knows how to help me please respond soon.
I don't really know what to do, I tried to ask the AI for support but it didn't help me much.

Is your project synced? try to clean and rebuild? once project is build without any error, you should be able to see the layout.

Couple of things you need to attempt:

Ensure you're on the latest Android Studio version
Go to File -> Invalidate caches... (and restart Android Studio)
Go to File -> Sync Project with Gradle Files
Clean, Build, and Run the app to ensure code is ok


I tried the 4 options you gave me but none of them worked, when I go to build I get an error message saying:
A build operation failed.
Could not move temporary workspace
What can I do?

Then I would say you need to ensure your project is able to build and run properly before you try and fix the Design Editor issue. See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78492004/android-studio-gradle-sync-error-could-not-move-temporary-workspace
